# MVC Refreshing DataTables Data

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, datatables, partial-views

I am using data tables along with MVC.

What I'm trying to achieve is updating the data inside a DataTable on 5 second interval, without refreshing the whole page, but I'm having trouble with the logic behind it.

At the moment I can populate the DataTable using my model or by using data returned in JSON format. But I seem to have problems with both.

### Model Approach

JQuery calls a controller which returns a partial view which contains the whole table which has been populated. This works and is quite straight forward.

However it seems unnecessary to return the HTML every call, and since the table is being pulled in from a partial view, and each time page numbers and other settings are lost.

### JSON Approach

JQuery calls a controller which returns the data we need in JSON format, this allows the relevant parts of the page to be updated.

However I don't see a way to update the data once it has been set, Apart from using DataTables built in AJAX call, which doesn't seem to allow for polling.

Any thoughts on whether these are good or bad approaches would be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: In general an AJAX JSON service seems like the way to go.  No sense in transferring more data than needed over and over again, or re-initializing the entire DataTables plugin over and over again on a new set of markup.  What actual problem have you encountered while doing this?  Are you just asking how to update data in DataTables?  They have considerable documentation, to include things like removing records and adding records.

Comment: To clarify, the datatables are just reflecting a database. Pretty much as you say I'm just trying to make the datatables reflect the updated from the database. I did have a look at the documentation but I couldn't seem a section on polling on a timer for updates.

Comment: I doubt there would be anything built-in for polling.  But you can have your own `setInterval()` instance which polls for new data and updates the client-side table.  Each time it executes just remove and re-add the rows from the DataTables instance.  https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()  https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data source is MSSQL, then you could look at using SignalR and SQLDependency as per this example https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874240/SignalR-Database-update-notifications-in-ASP-NET-M